# vertical center content in a boostrap column with 100% height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, vertical-alignment

columns need to be the whole height of the row but the content (text) still needs to be vertically centered.

```
<div class="row fixed-bottom mobile-navbar align-items-center">
    <router-link to="/" class="col h-100">Home</router-link>
    <router-link to="/scan" class="col h-100">Scan</router-link>
    <router-link to="/account" class="col h-100">Account</router-link>
  </div>
```

how do I do this?

I've tried to place spans inside the a elements and use py-auto, but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue: I had a class on my row called, mobile-navbar that gave a fixed height on the element, making it annoying to center the children. I removed the fixed height and let the children decide the height of the parent by using padding leaving them in the center vertically.

Answer (score 0):

h-100 takes the 100% size of the object it is in, so it cannot be centered because it is 100% vertical.
Delete the h-100s and give the container the following css or classes.

must be:

```
<div class="row h-100 align-items-center" > //must be bigger than router height you can write min height:200px;
<router-link to="/" class="col ">Home</router-link>
<router-link to="/scan" class="col ">Scan</router-link>
<router-link to="/account" class="col">Account</router-link>
</div>
```

alternative:

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center border" style="height:500px;">
        <div class="col border">1</div>
        <div class="col border">2</div>
        <div class="col border">3</div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: when I try you first example, the router-link elements aren't the full height of the row. This leaves an unclickable space between the top of the row and the top of the router links.